# Stuck with a 64-bit Windows 7 on a 32-bit machine

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad laptop, SL500, 2GB Ram (DDR2). Several days ago, I went to a repairman (for lack of a better word) to upgrade my Ram to 4GB. After he plugged in 4GB Ram, the repairman installed the 64-bit version of Windows 7 (I need it for some specific reasons), but it seems like he screwed up and was unable to boot Win 7 (it justs stops at the WIndows icon and "starting Windows"). Then, after all options have been tried, I decided to plug back the 2GB ram and go back to the way it was, but the problem is the OS is now 64 bit, while the RAM is 32 bit. Now I'm unable to do anything. When I try to turn on, it just stops at the Windows icon. When I try to do a safe mode, it simply stops at "Loading ...... ahcix64s.sys" . Please help me, thank you very much

Update: I was also unable to load the last known good configuration , since this is the only thing I see:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \Boot\BCD

  Status: 0xc000000f

  Info: An error occurred while trying to read the boot configuration data.
```

Comment: The amount of memory does not determine the bitness (64 or 32) of the processor.

Comment: You need to go back and see if he can give you a x32 windows 7.  You can use the 4gb so just make sure you get x32 put back on there. You need to talk to the repair tech about this issue. As he/she should've known this. And yes @Mokubai stated the ram does not determine your bitness.

Comment: But the repairman refused! Although he did give me a refund, he was unable to put everything back the way it was! So i'm afraid I'm on my own now.

Comment: According to [ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:SL500), the ThinkPad SL500 has a 64-bit processor.  (All the processor options listed are 64-bit.)  So 64-bit Windows should work; you do not need a 32-bit copy of Windows.

Comment: Did you also try 'Last Known Good Configuration' boot options? Also try with setting SATA Mode to IDE in BIOS/UEFI if that option is configurable.

Comment: So go back to a different repairman?  You obviously feel you don't have the skills to perform the upgrade yourself, even though, its literally plug and play.

Comment: Actually I have tried several repairmen already, but they were all incapable of fixing my problem. I guess I'll have to work on my own then.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to reinstall Windows from the USB, but no matter what i tried it always returned some sort of error. Later on, I realized that it does not recognize usb port 3.0, only port 2.0, which I don't have, so I decided to simply abandon Windows altogether and switch to Ubuntu. This was quite easy. Later on, if i want to return to Windows, I just have to resize the partition.